# Odd-Even subarrays

Tags: arrays, sub-array

You are given an array A of N positive integer values. A subarray of this array is called Odd-Even subarray if the number of odd integers in this subarray is equal to the number  of even integers in this subarray.

**Find the number of Odd-Even subarrays for the given array.**

```
int main(){
int n,i,j,count=0,sum;
scanf("%d",&n);
 int arr[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    sum=0;
    for(j=i;j<n;j+=2){
        sum+=(arr[j+1]+arr[j]);
        if(sum%2!=0)
                ++count;
    }
}
printf("%d",count);
return 0;}
```

**can anyone help me with my code**

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that if the sum up to a certain index is odd, then that means it is Odd-Even. However, your definition of Odd-Even states that the number of odd #s and even #s have to be the same. So your algorithm would fail in cases such as:
1, 2, 3, 5 -> sum is 11, but 3 odd 1 even.

Also, your first loop can also increment by twos since if the # of elements is odd, then there is no way the number of odd numbers will equal the number of even numbers.